# How to fix screen capture (video) issues with the standard tool in Ubuntu 23.04 Gnome?

Tags: 23.04, desktop-recording

Hardware:

- Lenovo Lenovo IdeaPad S540-14API
- AMD Ryzen™ 5 3500U with Radeon™ Vega Mobile Gfx × 8
- 8.0Gb RAM

I have already recorded several times videos on Ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic Kudu in FullHD, Wayland, and there was always normal results, regardless of the recording duration: [link to my youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/@foxintheheart)

But on Ubuntu 23.04 I see something like this:
[just one frame after 4 min recordinng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1SQ5.jpg)

And switching to an X.org session didn't help either. And I don't understand what is the reason and how to make everything work the way it works on Kinetic, i.e. correct and normal, i.e. just right.